# Bootstrap horizontal scrolling

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, scroll

I am using the following HTML code:

```html
<div id="list">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">2</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">n-times</div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to display one row with infinity columns that scroll when they overflow the container.

How can I do this?

I tried to set a fixed `width` for the `#list` container, and have also set `overflow-x: auto`.

Comment: Bootstrap only supports 12 columns, not infinity (that would require an infinitely large stylesheet).  You would need to overwrite the "width:25%" that `col-md-3` sets, to something fixed probably.

Comment: So, what is solution then?

Comment: No, the way that bootstrap handles columns is with percentages, so to extrapolate the same method would take lots and lots of classes. But if you don't want to do it the bootstrap way, why use bootstrap? There are other grid systems.

Comment: Actually Bootstrap *does* support more than 12 columns units in a single row and wouldn't require more CSS selectors. Again native flexbox in Bootstrap 4 so it is the Bootstrap way. You're confusing 12 grid units with allowed columns per row.

Comment: This question is not a dup of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26679160/bootstrap-3-more-than-12-columns-in-a-row). This question is how to create horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It's [okay to exceed 12 column units in a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732763/bootstrap-3-nested-row-can-i-have-columns-add-up-to-more-then-12). It causes the [columns to wrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping), but you can override the wrapping with flexbox.

**Bootstrap 4** uses flexbox, and the utility classes to get a horizontal scrolling layout..

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row flex-row flex-nowrap">
        <div class="col-3">
           ..
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
           ..
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
           ..
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
           ..
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
           ..
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
           ..
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
           ..
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
           ..
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Bootstrap 4 Demo:** http://codeply.com/go/GoFQqQAFhN

Also see: [Horizontally scrollable list of cards in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35993300/horizontally-scrollable-list-of-cards-in-bootstrap/42117768#42117768)

For **Bootstrap 3**, it would be done with some CSS for the flexbox..
.

```
row > .col-xs-3 {
    display:flex;
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 25%
}

.flex-nowrap {
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap!important;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap!important;
    flex-wrap: nowrap!important;
}
.flex-row {
    display:flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal!important;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal!important;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row!important;
    -ms-flex-direction: row!important;
    flex-direction: row!important;
}
```

**Bootstrap 3 Demo**: http://codeply.com/go/P13J3LuBIM

Comment: Not working with bootstrap 5

Answer (score 3):

One other way :

**CSS**:

```
#list .row {white-space:nowrap;}
#list .row > div {display:inline-block;float:none;}
```

**Js for horizontal scrolling:**

```
window.addEventListener('mousewheel', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var step = -100;  
    if (e.wheelDelta < 0) {
      step *= -1;
    }
    var newPos = window.pageXOffset + step;
    $('body').scrollLeft(newPos);    
})
```

**Bootply** : https://www.bootply.com/pbenard/usmX12rxgP

Answer (score 1):

The bootstrap 5 variant of Carol's solution is

```
<div class="row overflow-x-auto flex-nowrap">
  <!-- your cols here -->
</div>
```