# Css-Bootstrap panels display inline with overflow

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, panel

*Scenario*

Firstly here is my fiddle: `-->` https://jsfiddle.net/edxcbn4n/1/ `<--`

As you can see I have three panels on the first tab, but I need these panels to not display above and below but rather side by side, so I can use the scroll function to scroll across to the next one. I can't figure out how to do it. Everything I've done so far and tried so far is in the fiddle.

*Question*

**How do you make the panels display side by side, so i can scroll across from one to the other.**

Comment: Try reading about css floats or flex layouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Bootstrap grid inside the `tab-pane`..

```
   <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active container-fluid" id="home">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4"><div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Basic panel example
                </div>
            </div></div>
                <div class="col-md-4"><div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Basic panel example
                </div>
            </div></div>
                <div class="col-md-4"><div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Basic panel example
                </div>
            </div></div>
            </div>
   </div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/JMdfZvNGDF

***EDIT:*** To exceed more than 3 panels in the row, use flexbox to override the default Bootstrap column wrapping. Just add `flex-row` to the `row`

```
.flex-row > .col-md-4 {
    display:flex;
    flex: 0 0 33%;
    max-width: 33%
}

.flex-row {
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap!important;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap!important;
    flex-wrap: nowrap!important;
    display:flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal!important;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal!important;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row!important;
    -ms-flex-direction: row!important;
    flex-direction: row!important;
}
```

Comment: This wont work because when i add more panels the scroll feature still wont be utilised, try adding 3 more panels to the example you sent me

Comment: Your question didn't say more than 3. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41963196/171456

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what i was looking for update your question and i will accept