# Bootstrap 4 row: scroll left-right when screen width < 700px

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am using Boostrap 4 row

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="card"></div>
   <div class="card"></div>
   <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

I would like to make it 'left-right scrollable' on mobile, as "responsive-table" would do for tables.

Here is a schema to explain it more clearly enter image description here

[image]

Comment: this is not available in bootstrap, you have to code this functionality yourself.

Comment: Looks like you've asked this before? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56967619/bootstrap-4-card-deck-scroll-left-right-on-mobile .. Also cards don't go inside row, columns do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is to put the cards in columns and set a min/max width on the columns. Use `flex-nowrap` on the row to prevent wrapping.

```
.col {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 300px;
}
```

https://codeply.com/go/HDABlirIsA

Also see: [Bootstrap horizontal scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41962898/bootstrap-horizontal-scrolling/41963196#41963196)