# Horizontal scroll in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, horizontal-scrolling

I'm trying to get a horizontal scroll for some cards I have for mobile view `@media only screen and (max-width : 480px)`. I have read other posts here, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35993300/horizontally-scrollable-list-of-cards-in-bootstrap), but none seem to work for me.  I guess that one of my possible issues is that right now my cards are stacked one over the other.

This is what I have now:

[image]

And this is what I need to achieve:

[image]

```css
.mobile-card-container {
  display: block;
}

.card-background {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 1px rgba(0, 51, 102, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 1px rgba(0, 51, 102, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 1px rgba(0, 51, 102, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <!-- Mobile Card Container -->
  <div class="col-12 mobile-card-container">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- Card 48 cuotas -->
      <div class="col-10 card-background simulacion mx-auto" style="border: 1px solid red;">
        Card content
      </div>
      <!-- /Card 48 cuotas -->
      <!-- Card 36 cuotas-->
      <div class="col-10 card-background simulacion mx-auto" style="border: 1px solid blue;">
        Card Content
      </div>
      <!-- /Card 36 cuotas -->
      <!-- Card 24 cuotas -->
      <div class="col-10 card-background simulacion mx-auto" style="border: 1px solid green;">
        Card Content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For an approach to this, you will have to change the default behaviours of the Bootstrap classes. We will have to use [flex-nowrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#wrap) on the cards container for the smallest media screen and change the **overflow-x** style to **auto**. In summary, we will use the nexts main changes:

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 576px)
{
  .mobile-card-container > .row {
    overflow-x: auto;
  }
}
```

Note that I used `max-width: 576px` for compatibility with the currents [Bootstrap Breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints).

**HTML structure**

```
<!-- Mobile Card Container -->
<div class="container-fluid mobile-card-container">
  <div class="row text-center flex-nowrap flex-sm-wrap">
    <!-- Cards will be here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

So, for **XS** screen devices, the `flex-nowrap` class will apply in conjunction with the previous defined style, approaching what you where searching for. On the others type of screens (**SM, MD, LG**) the default behaviour of Bootstrap classes will be keeped (Note the usage of **flex-sm-wrap** class).

To finish, you can check the next working example (play with the windows resize on the full screen mode):

```css
@media only screen and (max-width : 576px)
{
  .mobile-card-container > .row {
    overflow-x: auto;
  }
}

.card-background {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 16px 5px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 1px rgba(0, 51, 102, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 1px rgba(0, 51, 102, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 1px rgba(0, 51, 102, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Mobile Card Container -->
<div class="container-fluid mobile-card-container">
  <div class="row text-center flex-nowrap flex-sm-wrap">
    
    <!-- Card 48 cuotas -->
    <div class="col-10 card-background mx-sm-auto bg-danger">
      Card content
    </div>
    <!-- /Card 48 cuotas -->
      
    <!-- Card 36 cuotas-->
    <div class="col-10 card-background mx-sm-auto bg-primary">
      Card Content
    </div>
    <!-- /Card 36 cuotas -->
      
    <!-- Card 24 cuotas -->
    <div class="col-10 card-background mx-sm-auto bg-danger">
      Card Content
    </div>
    <!-- /Card 24 cuotas -->
      
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    .mobile-card-container {
      display: block;
    }

    .card-background {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      border-radius: 6px;
      margin-top: 16px;
      height: 100px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 1px rgba(0, 51, 102, 0.1);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 1px rgba(0, 51, 102, 0.1);
      box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 1px rgba(0, 51, 102, 0.1);
    }
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- Mobile Card Container -->
      <div class="col-md-12 mobile-card-container">
        <div class="row">
          <!-- Card 48 cuotas -->
          <div class="col-md-4 card-background simulacion mx-auto" style="border: 1px solid red;">
            Card content
          </div>
          <!-- /Card 48 cuotas -->
          <!-- Card 36 cuotas-->
          <div class="col-md-4 card-background simulacion mx-auto" style="border: 1px solid blue;">
            Card Content
          </div>
          <!-- /Card 36 cuotas -->
          <!-- Card 24 cuotas -->
          <div class="col-md-4 card-background simulacion mx-auto" style="border: 1px solid green;">
            Card Content
          </div>
</div>
```

Comment: col-md-4      what are you trying to do ?

Comment: I don't understand the col-md-4 in this case.